# ObjectAl latency settings

Tags: ios, audio, latency

using ObjectAl for an iOS soundboard app. Working really well so far. If i can tweak the latency just a little more that would be awesome.
Right now I am just using it straight up with OALSimpleAudio.
Anyone know if there are parameters I should adjust in OALSimpleAudio.m file to try to get the latency lower? Thanks!
Very new to programming but having fun!

```
#import "BTM_soundView.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "pandrum_appDelegate.h"
#import "ObjectAL.h"


@implementation BTM_soundView
- (id) init
{
    if(nil != (self = [super init]))
    {
        // We don't want ipod music to keep playing since
        // we have our own bg music.
        [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].allowIpod = NO;

        // Mute all audio if the silent switch is turned on.
        [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].honorSilentSwitch = YES;

        // This loads the sound effects into memory so that
        // there's no delay when we tell it to play them.
        [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"ding.caf"];
        [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"templebell.caf"];
        [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"snare.wav"];
         [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"snare.caf"];
    }
    return self;
}





@synthesize viewController = _viewController;



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




}

/*
// made .caf file in Terminal for each sound
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 templebell.wav templebell.caf
*/



- (IBAction)SSound1{


  [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"snare.wav"];



}
- (IBAction)SSound2{

    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"templebell.caf"];
}


- (IBAction)SSound3{


    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"ding.caf"];

}

- (IBAction)SSound4{


    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"snare.caf"];

}



@end
```

Comment: what latency do you have now and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, i haven't tracked the timing but i can tell it's a little late than i'd like. Wasn't sure if there is a parameter to adjust? I'm using .caf files as recommended. here is my code

Comment: standard latencies in underlying CoreAudio are roughly 23ms ... "a little late" may be 23 or may be more or less?

Comment: Yes it's definitely doing pretty well. just wasn't sure if there were tweaks. i do have to learn a ton more. I'm thinking from the code in my original post the [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect: stuff should go in ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: no reason for doing that, respectively there won't be any improvement as far as i can see

Comment: Thanks for ur time! I've got it sorted well now. One thing that helps big time is to make sure to trigger sounds on the Down tap not on the Up! Doh!